# make an Setup exe file of c++ VS2010

Tags: c++, installation

I've done app by c++ . It's serial port programming/win app.
It's got many files and I would like to make an exe file(setup file to install on client's pc) for delivering thru customers.
I did many research and as far as i see i couldnt.

Any way to do that ?

Would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you build your app now? Does it produce a DLL? Unless you've mucked with your project build settings or started off your project as a library project, you should have an `.exe` in your build folder.

Comment: I am following that:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That's right I am having an .exe in my build or release folder but that is exec file its not a setup file

Comment: Add a Setup and Deployment project to your solution.  Not available on the Express edition.

Comment: @mehmet, that means you really want to build an installer.

Comment: @Hans: I've got with me the full version. the thing is to make it really strange. It's already exe file after compiling but I would like that customer is getting setup file after installing having my exe file and some of files which references of images or text file

Comment: Do you *actually* need an installer?  There are few things more annoying than an installer when a ZIP file will do...

Comment: If I cannot do by visual studio it seems yes I need an installer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a [setup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx) and add it to your solution.

EDIT

You may also like to check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z11b431t.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyh6k4k4.aspx) links.

Comment: so, how could be able to include the files of the project what has got images and access db ?

Comment: It works but I doesnt take the files of what I have like images/excel sheets etc.... how could be?

Comment: @mehmet altuntas: you have to add extra files using 'actions' in file system editor.

Answer (score 1):

So after the comments, I'm pretty sure what you really want is to build an installer for your application which will package up your built executables with all it necessary libraries and what not, so that you can deliver a single file to your customers and have them install it.

A basic way is the way a lot of open source/free software projects do it - supply an archive/zip/whatever file that the user downloads and unzips on their own machine. I don't really recommend this way unless your users are all technical.

At a previous company we [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which is really nice, easy to learn, and free.

Comment: I've installed that. could not understand

Comment: @mehmet - did you read their documentation? [InnoSetup Documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp). The link by Donotalo might be easier since it's part of VS.

Answer (score 1):

nsis is another option.  http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page . It can create windows installers and is script based.